# "woff", "woff2" works on localhost but not on web servers and giving console errors

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, fonts, configuration, font-family

I'm using font-awesome, and most of font-families with "woff", "woff2" extensions in ASP.NET MVC environment. They are working extremely in localhost.

But when it is come to deployment environment, most of the times we can't get actual font-family styles as localhost.

What can we do to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define font file extensions adding this code to web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register the MIME types of the fonts on the deployment server, use the web.config to do so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Note: Im adding a remove tag just to be sure, because if type is registered it would throw an error.
Also, if you are using MVC, check your resource bundles, since deploying release applications mess up with the paths of the resources.